# Wordpress Theme - Changing elements too many if's

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a very complex theme in Wordpress. This is my first major wp project that I haven't modified a theme.  One section of the site has slightly different visual elements in the header so I am  doing this

```
<?php if(is_page(537)) { ?><div id="header-right"><?php } ?>
<?php if(!is_page(537)) { ?><div id="media-header-right"><?php } ?>
```

The issue is I have 10 of these statements all over the place. It works but I can't help to think there is a more elegant solution available.

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
&raquo; Blog Archive
<?php } ?>
<?php wp_title(); ?>
-
<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/style.css" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/fonts/stylesheet.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/slider-theme/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/jquery.tweet.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/roll-over.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/gmap-somalia.js"></script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<?php if(!is_page(537)) { ?> <body <?php body_class(); ?>> <?php } ?>
<?php if(is_page(537)) { ?><body class="media-showcase"><?php } ?>

<div class="container">
<!--Start Container -->
<div id="header">
<!--Start Header -->
<div class="logo"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name')?>"  width="269" height="89" rel="home"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/logo.png" width="269" height="89" alt="Global Enrichment Foundation"></a> </div>

<?php if(is_page(537)) { ?><div id="media-header-right"><?php } ?>
<?php if(!is_page(537)) { ?><div id="header-right"><?php } ?>

<!--Start Header Right -->
<?php if(is_page(537)) { ?> <div class="media-donate-buton">
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/donate" title="Donate">Donate</a> </div> <?php } ?>
<?php if(!is_page(537)) { ?>
<div class="donate-buton"> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/donate" title="Donate">Donate</a> </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if(is_page(537)) { ?>
<div class="search">
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<p>
<input type="text" class="field" name="m" id="m" placeholder="Search..." />
<input type="submit" class="submit search" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="ok" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if(!is_page(537)) { ?>
<div class="search">
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<p>
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search..." />
<input type="submit" class="submit m-search" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="ok" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if(is_page(537)) { ?>

<div id="media">
<h3>Archive</h3>
<select id="standard-dropdown" name="standard-dropdown" class="custom-class1 custom-class2" style="width: 148px;">
<option value="0" class="test-class-0" selected="selected">Select a Month</option>
<option value="1" class="test-class-1">January</option>
<option value="2" class="test-class-2">February</option>
<option value="3" class="test-class-3">March</option>
<option value="4" class="test-class-4">April</option>
<option value="5" class="test-class-5">May</option>
<option value="6" class="test-class-6">June</option>
<option value="7" class="test-class-7">July</option>
<option value="8" class="test-class-8">August</option>
<option value="9" class="test-class-9">September</option>
<option value="10" class="test-class-10">October</option>
<option value="11" class="test-class-11">November</option>
<option value="12" class="test-class-12">December</option>
</select>
<select name="empty-dropdown" style="width: 148px;">
<option value="0" class="test-class-0" selected="selected">Select a Year</option>
<option value="1" class="test-class-1">2009</option>
<option value="2" class="test-class-2">2010</option>
<option value="3" class="test-class-3">2012 </option>
<option value="4" disabled="disabled">2013</option>
<option value="5" disabled="disabled">2014</option>
</select>
<ul class="socialicons">
<li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/AmandaLindhout" title="twitter" target='_blank'>Twitter</a></li>
<li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/AmandaLindhoutPage" title="facebook" target='_blank'>Facebook</a></li>
<li class="vimeo"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/globalenrichment" title="you tube" target='_blank'>You Tube</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if(!is_page(537)) { ?>
<div id="latest-twitts">
<h3>The Latest</h3>
<div id='custom' class="query">&nbsp;</div><!-- twitter via jquery -->
<h3>Stay Updated</h3>
<ul class="socialicons">
<li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/AmandaLindhout" title="twitter" target='_blank'>Twitter</a></li>
<li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/GlobalEnrichmentFoundation" title="facebook" target='_blank'>Facebook</a></li>
<li class="vimeo"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/globalenrichment" title="you tube" target='_blank'>You Tube</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>


<?php if(!is_page(537)) { ?>
<div id="side_bar"></div>
<?php dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar'); ?>
</div> <?php } ?>
<!--End Header-Right -->
<div class='cssmenu'>
<!--Start Menu -->
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container'=>'', 'menu_id'=>'nav' ,'menu_class' => 'main-menu','theme_location' =>        'main-menu','depth'=> 2 ) ); ?>
</div>
</div>
<!--End Menu -->
</div>
<!--End Header -->
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Both statements do the same thing so what's the point of the if at all? Unless there's more code between that you're not including. You could use an else block instead of two ifs.

Comment: Added more code so you can see what I am talking about

Comment: you can make two templates and include the entire template if its page 537 or keep it as is but i'd change it from 2 ifs to an if/else.

Answer (score 0):

Either add another page template or a new header file. It is much cleaner.

Here is a tutorial that shows pretty much the easiest way of adding a page template

http://wpmu.org/wordpress-custom-page-template/

and more information

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

instead of having

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

in your new template (that might not be exactly the right code but you get the point) custom code your new header into the template.

OR you can create another header file and use the if statements that you currently are using just once in the page template.

example of this

```
if(is_page(537)) {
     get new header
 } else {
      get original header
 }
```